# CURL Working with one subdomain but not working on other one on same server

Tags: curl, subdomain

CURL is working with one subdomain, but not working with other one on same server.
Below code:

- is working with "http://api.mineralsforall.in"
- is **not working** with "http://appapinew.mineralsforall.in"

This is the code I am using:

```php
   $curl = curl_init();

   switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }

   // OPTIONS:
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

   // EXECUTE:
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   print_r($result);
   if(!$result){echo curl_error($curl); return "Connection Failure";}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add some more details, what do you mean by "not working", what result are you getting? Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The second url, "http://appapinew.mineralsforall.in", redirects to the HTTPS version, you should include

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

or change url to the https version